# Streaming request results across function call in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a use case where my API has to return a huge amount of data to the calling function. I'm using the requests library in python. I have set stream = true. 
The response is able to hold the close to 2 GB data but I would now like to return the results to the calling python script in a stream rather than as one single response object. 
How would I do this. 
Currently I'm writing everything to a list and then passing the list as the function result. 
What I would like to do is stream this across function calls instead.

Comment: The `stream` argument is about streaming data _from the Internet_, not 'across your code' (the latter doesn't even make sense).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/):

> By default, when you make a request, the body of the response is downloaded immediately. You can override this behaviour and defer downloading the response body until you access the `Response.content` attribute with the stream parameter.
>
> You can further control the workflow by use of the `Response.iter_content()` and `Response.iter_lines()` methods. Alternatively, you can read the undecoded body from the underlying urllib3 `urllib3.HTTPResponse` at `Response.raw`.

You may also want to read up on [generator functions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) for how to return a sequence of data one item at a time.